# incrementing the value in map using insert c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert

I have the following problem - I want to count the occurrences of each word in a file. I'm using a `map<string,Count>` so the key is the string object representing the word, and the value being looked up is the object that keeps count of the strings so that :

```
class Count {
    int i;
public:
    Count() : i(0) {}
    void operator++(int) { i++; } // Post-increment
    int& val() { return i; }
};
```

The problem is that I want to use `insert()` instead of the `operator[]`. Here is the code.

```
typedef map<string, Count> WordMap;
typedef WordMap::iterator WMIter;

int main( ) {

    ifstream in("D://C++ projects//ReadF.txt");

    WordMap wordmap;
    string word;
    WMIter it;
    while (in >> word){
        //  wordmap[word]++; // not that way

        if((it= wordmap.find(word)) != wordmap.end()){ //if the word already exists 
        wordmap.insert(make_pair(word, (*it).second++); // how do I increment the value ? 
        }else{
          ...
         }

    for (WMIter w = wordmap.begin();
        w != wordmap.end(); w++)
        cout << (*w).first << ": "
        << (*w).second.val() << endl;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using a `std::map<string, std::size_t>` and `wordmap[word]++;`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm doing some exercises and I had to do it with `insert()`. Anyway the answer below made it clear for me.

Comment: If the value already exists, `insert` will not insert anything.

Comment: if you wanting to use `insert` is the problem, then the solution is: change your mind and dont use `insert` :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that I want to use `insert()` instead of the `operator[]`

...why? [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) cannot mutate existing values. `operator[]` is the right job for this.

If you really want to use `insert` *(please don't)*, you first need to `erase` the existing value, if present:

```
if((it= wordmap.find(word)) != wordmap.end())
{
     const auto curr = it->second; // current number of occurrences
     wordmap.erase(word);
     wordmap.insert(make_pair(word, curr + 1)); 
}
```

Comment: Could look nicer with C++17: `if (auto it = wordmap.find(word); it != wordmap.end()) { ... }`

Answer (score 4):

Could you refactor so as not to use find but simply attempt the insert?

Insert always returns a `pair<iter*, bool>`. The bool is 0 if it finds the key, and the iter* points to the existing pair. So we can take the pointer to the pair and increment the value:

```
// On successful insertion, we get a count of 1 for that word:
auto result_pair = wordmap.insert( { word, 1 } );
// Increment the count if the word is already there: 
if (!result_pair.second)
    result_pair.first->second++;
```

It was my first time posting. I'm learning C++ and welcome feedback on my idea.